# How to find a character in the middle of a string?

Tags: c, string

I want to find 3 characters in a string.

I already use `strchr` and `strrchr` but I cannot get the middle char.

For example:

```
hehoho
```

If I use `strchr` I get the first `h`.

If I use `strrchr` I get the last `h`.

How can I get the the middle `h`: `hehoho`?

```
char *p;
char* q;
int loc2;
int loc;
char ch[100];
char s[100] = "heheho"

p = strrchr(s, ch);
q = strchr(s, ch);

loc = (int)(p - s);
loc2 = (int)(q - s);

if ( q != NULL)
{   
    a[loc] = ch;
    a[loc2] = ch;
}
```

Comment: The thing about strings is that they are really arrays of null-terminated characters. A pointer to a string is typically a pointer to the first character in the string, but it doesn't have to be: You can have a pointer to *any* character in the string. That means you could use e.g. [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) in a loop to find all `'h'` in the string, just by passing the pointer (plus one) returned by the previous call to `strchr`.

Comment: you need to provide more rules, e.g. is h going to be any character after 3rd position? in a string 'hah' there is no middle 'h'. what types of input strings you are expecting? you can then use regex library or just occurrence attribute for searching

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thankyou so much! you're so kind!!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep calling `strchr` until you run out of found characters. The function returns `NULL` when the character isn't found, so maybe something like this:

```
for(const char* ptr=s; ptr!=NULL && *ptr!='\0'; ptr=strchr(ptr+1, key))
{
  index[found_count] = ptr-s;
  found_count++;
}
```

This stores down the array index of every found character that matches the character "key", then keeps searching until it finds no more matches and `strchr` returns NULL. So it finds *all* occurrences.

Each time you tell `strchr` to look at the current position + 1. If not for the + 1, you'd keep getting the same result in infinity.

The check `*ptr!='\0'` for null termination isn't really necessary but catches the case of an empty input string.

`ptr-s` is pointer arithmetic and gives a integer type corresponding to the position in the string. It will only get executed when the pointer actually points at a valid array item.

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
  const char s[100] = "heheho";
  const char key = 'h';
  int found_count = 0;
  int index[10];

  for(const char* ptr=s; ptr!=NULL && *ptr!='\0'; ptr=strchr(ptr+1, key))
  {
    index[found_count] = ptr-s;
    found_count++;
  }

  for(size_t i=0; i<found_count; i++)
  {
    printf("Found %c at index %d.\n", key, index[i]);
  }

  printf("So the middle one is at index %d.", index[found_count/2]);
}
```

Output:

```
Found h at index 0.
Found h at index 2.
Found h at index 4.
So the middle one is at index 2.
```

Comment: The initialization of `ptr` should be the result of the first call to `strchr`, otherwise you'll use the first character of the string as the first found character, even if it's a character you're not looking for.